# SPServices $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker not working for required field

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, jquery, csom, spservices

I am using SharePoint 2010 and SPServices to get values from people picker in custom field. It is working fine but not fetching data for required fields.
can anyone help me with this.

```
var PP = $().SPFindPeoplePicker({ peoplePickerDisplayName: 'peoplepicker_display_name' });
for(var i=0;i<PP.dictionaryEntries.length;i++)
{
    PP += PP.dictionaryEntries[i].AccountName +","
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your code to your post

Comment: code has been added in question

Comment: It looks like you first set `PP` to the object returned by SPServices, but then try to append strings (`AccountName`) to it. Did you mean to build a string variable?

Comment: no.. the PP.dictionaryEntries return zero item

Comment: So `peoplepicker_display_name` is the name of your column? What happens if you use `console.log(PP);` with the console open?

Comment: It return object which contain empty array. I think it is issue with only required field display name

Comment: You could verify that by temporarily turning off required for that field

Comment: I think there is bug in spservice when in display name of column there is * mark of required field. when i remove * from <nobar></nobar> it is working fine. 
can any have idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

i solve above issue with help of below link.

http://ecarlos.net/post/2012/10/19/Get-PeopleEditor-(PeoplePicker)-values-in-sharepoint-2010-using-SPServices.aspx

basically  SPFindPeoplePicker search for label name of column. if you have required field * mark next to you field name then spserivce did find column name. just remove or shift * mark from label name.

above link is given solution not able to add my HTML here as example